# onMessage data: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'(Want to print the message on console)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the error when im trying to send the message from the `firebase messaging` i would be really glad if anyone could explain me this how to make it correct

```
W/FirebaseMessaging(11937): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
W/FirebaseMessaging(11937): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(11937): broadcast received for message
I/flutter (11937): onMessage data: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'
```

This is my `pushnotification.dart:` file

```
import 'package:cab_driver/globalvariables.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class PushNotificationService {

  final FirebaseMessaging fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('getInitialMessage data: $message');

    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print("onMessage data: $message");
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessageOpenedApp data: $message');

    });
  }

  Future<String>getToken() async{

    String token = await fcm.getToken();
    print('token: $token');

    DatabaseReference tokenRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('drivers/${currentFirebaseUser.uid}/token');
    tokenRef.set(token);

    fcm.subscribeToTopic('alldrivers');
    fcm.subscribeToTopic('allusers');
  }
}
```

I wanted to print the message which i'm sending from the firebase messaging but giving the same thing as `I/flutter (11937): onMessage data: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'` plz anyone can help im really stuck not understanding anything

Answer (score 1):

Since `RemoteMessage` doesn't override `toString()`. Better alternative is to print `message.toMap()`.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("Message: ${message.toMap()}");
});
```

And if you want it to be in JSON format, use

```
print("Message: ${jsonEncode(message.toMap())}");
```

Answer (score 0):

`RemoteMessage` doesn't override `toString()` so that's why you're seeing `Instance of 'RemoteMessage`.

You could simply print whatever you want from the RemoteMessage object. For example if you were interested in the `data` property:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("onMessage data: ${message.data}");
});
```

You could do something similar for the [other properties in RemoteMessage](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage-class.html#instance-properties).

Comment: can u please check this one out @Noel (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374859/unhandled-exception-nosuchmethoderror-the-method-was-called-on-null-not)  in not getting this